# File much larger after copying with it.bytes

Tags: groovy

I wanted to copy a file from one location to another using a Groovy script. I found that the copied files was orders of magnitude larger than the original file after copying. 
After some trial and error I found the correct way to copy but am still puzzled as to why it should be bigger.

```
def existingFile = new File("/x/y/x.zip")
def newFile1 = new File("/x/y/y.zip")
def newFile2 = new File("/x/y/z.zip")

new File(newFile1) << new File(existingFile).bytes
new File(newFile2).bytes = new File(existingFile).bytes
```

If you run this code, *newFile1* will be much larger than *existingFile*, while *newFile2* will be the same size as *existingFile*.
Note that both zip files are valid afterwards.

Does anyone know why this happens? Am I use the first copy incorrectly? Or is it something odd in my setup?

Comment: Did y.zip already exist before you ran this code?  The `<<` approach will _append_ the specified bytes to the end of the file, whereas `x.bytes = y` will overwrite the file.  And since the ZIP format can tolerate garbage on the front of a zip file (to allow for self-extracting stubs, etc.), any file to which you append ZIP data will be a valid zip file.

Comment: Thanks Ian! This seems to be the issue. I have a bug in my code that loops a number of times, copying the file over and over again. Because I used the << operator it was appending to the file over and over again.

Comment: Glad it helped, I've re-posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file already exists before this code is called then you'll get different behaviour from `<<` and `.bytes = ...`

```
file << byteArray
```

will *append* the contents of `byteArray` to the end of the file, whereas

```
file.bytes = byteArray
```

will *overwrite* the file with the specified content.  When the `byteArray` is ZIP data, both versions will give you a result that is a valid ZIP file, because the ZIP format can cope with arbitrary data *pre*pended to the beginning of the file before the actual ZIP data without invalidating the file (typically this is used for things like self-extracting `.exe` stubs).